# Session permissions to certain routes

Tags: node.js, session

I'm having issues, mainly I'm reading lot of things and confusing my self.
I have an app with 9 partial routes.

I have 2 sessions **res.session.role** of **user** and **visitor**
I am trying to allow access to all partials by **user** and allow access to 2 partials if you are a **visitor**

sessions are created from an ldap search on load.

How would I look at going about it?

### routes

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when('/',{templateUrl: '/partial/home'})
...
...
and so on...
})
```

### views.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
})
```

### app.js

```
app.use('/', routes)
app.use('api', api)
```

I have tried this with

```
function rolecheck(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.role === 'user'){
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('/#/flow')
    }
}
```

This fails with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 0):

Create the middleware module, that will check the user's role, and if the user passes the validation, middleware will execute next() callback, else will redirect user somewhere
then add this middleware to your routes like this:

```
app.use('/', middleware, routes);
```

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS means you have created the forever redirect loop, because the visitor has been redirected to the route, which contains validation, then the visitor is redirecting again and again

Comment: yes, this is the bit I dont understand, how to stop it or change the route so it doesnt require validation

Comment: you have 2 public routes, and other are private. I would solve the problem using 2 routers `app.use('/public', publicRouter);` and `app.use('/private', validationMiddleware, privateRouter);` in the validation middleware if the user doesnt pass the validation, it will be redirected somewhere to /public/*** route or to /